# Library for CHCSVParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, parsing

I want to import a csv file from a remote server.For this purpose i am using the CHCSVParser provided by @[Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong).I have imported the files from Git hub provided by Dave.When i try to compile the code after importing the CHCSV.h header file, i am getting framework error
     (      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CHCSVParser", referenced from:).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me the **CHCSVParser** file has not been added to Target.

To do so, Right click the **CHCSVParser** file in Xcode

- Click **GetInfo**
- Go to **Targets** tab and check if the checkbox next to your target project is checked? If not, do check that checkbox.
- Clean and Rebuild your code.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ya actually i figured that out afterwards...i actually forgot to import the CHCSV Parser files into the project!!!